# Is it possible to have a switching UNIQUE index within a table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have a server set up which on login of the user, logs their userID, IP and if the IP already exists in the database it adds an occurrence next to their IP and userID, like shown below. The duplicate key is currently on UserID. If I put no key then instead of it detecting that a row with that IP or UserID already exists, it makes a new row, for every login, which causes a lot of trouble.

I've tried putting the duplicate key on IP but if a user accesses the server with the same IP but a different UserID, it'll add an occurrence to the IP of the original user as the IP already exists and the new UserID won't be added to the database.

Table Structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ip_user` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `occurencies` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `userid` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Query on login:

```sql
glob.db.execute("""INSERT INTO ip_user (userid, ip, occurencies) VALUES (%s, %s, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE occurencies = occurencies + 1""", [userID, ip])
```

My hopeful outcome would be that it logs every new IP with the corresponding UserID, but if an old user signs in with that IP it'll add it as an occurrence.

Thank you!

Comment: There's no *"switching"* unique key in any database, it's literally impossible to implement it. Your `UNIQUE` key should be `(user_id, ip)`, then your `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` would work the way you described it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you want, but I assume you want to log every different userId and Ip pair. 
In this case, what you need is a unique key with  userId and Ip (not sure about mysql syntax, sorry):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ip_user` (
`userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`occurencies` int(11) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `userid_ip` (`userid`, `ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**EDIT**: Also, the official mysql documentacion might be helpful in that regard: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/multiple-column-indexes.html